# Centering a resizable image in CSS

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center an image to the exact center of a certain div. The image must keep it's original aspect ratio but also has to be able to grow and shrink, depending on the browsers width and height.

To be more exact: the container fills the whole window, it has a padding of 100px on each side. Inside the container is an image which fills that padded div either horizontally or vertically, depending on its aspect ratio. And at last, that image has to be positioned in the center of that all.

Here's my code:

```css
main {

}

main figure {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    height: calc( 100vh - 200px );
}

main figure img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/03/07/uno.jpg" />
    </figure>
</main>
```

I hope it's clear enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your image seems already centered to me. What is wrong with your current code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set your wrapper element to `position:relative`
2. Set your img element to have the following CSS:

   ```
   img{
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
   ```

This should center the image directly in the center of your wrapper.

Comment: Perfect and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using bootstrap framework which supports responsive web design. By using the class named img-responsive you will be able to make the image responsive to the width and height of the browser.

- Include bootstrap JavaScript to the HTML
- Include bootstrap CSS to the HTML
- Write CSS for centering the image and padding
- Add img-responsive class to the image

Here is an example for bootstrap responsive image
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h